# Dúvida quanto ao uso de model na view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma entidade chamada Pedido. Criei na pasta Model uma classe que carrega os Pedidos, chamada de **GetPedidos**. Bem, ao criar a o controller, adicionei uma view à **Action Index**. Ao construir a view, fiz com que ela usasse a model **GetPedidos**. Quando eu rodo, me dá esse erro:

> O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do
>   tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TSL.Domain.Entities.Pedido]',
>   mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSL.Models.GetPedidos]'.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: O item de
>   modelo inserido no dicionário é do
>   tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TSL.Domain.Entities.Pedido]',
>   mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSL.Models.GetPedidos]'.

Entendi o erro, só não sei como alterar isso, ou seja, se devo ou não usar o model **GetPedidos**

**EDIT1**

GetPedidos

```
public class GetPedidos : RepositoryData<Pedido, int>
    {
        public override void Delete(Pedido entity)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(StringConnection))
            {
                string sql = "DELETE Pedido Where Id_Pedido=@Id";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", entity.Id);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

        public override void DeleteById(int id)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(StringConnection))
            {
                string sql = "DELETE Pedido Where Id=@Id";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

        public override List<Pedido> GetAll()
        {
            string sql = "Select Id_Pedido, Id_Cliente, Num_Pedido, Dt_Entrega, Valor_Total FROM Pedido ORDER BY Num_Pedido";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(StringConnection))
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                List<Pedido> list = new List<Pedido>();
                Pedido p = null;
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            p = new Pedido();
                            p.Id = (int)reader["Id-Pedido"];
                            p.Numero = reader["Num_Pedido"].ToString();
                            p.DtEntrega = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Dt_Entrega"]);
                            p.ValorTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["ValorTotal"]);
                            p.IdCliente = (int)reader["Id_Cliente"];
                            list.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
                return list;
            }
        }


        public override Pedido GetById(int id)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(StringConnection))
            {
                string sql = "Select Id_Pedido, Id_Cliente, Num_Pedido, Dt_Entrega, Valor_Total FROM Pedido WHERE Id_Pedido=@Id";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                Pedido p = null;
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                p = new Pedido();
                                p.Id = (int)reader["Id-Pedido"];
                                p.Numero = reader["Num_Pedido"].ToString();
                                p.DtEntrega = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Dt_Entrega"]);
                                p.ValorTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["ValorTotal"]);
                                p.IdCliente = (int)reader["Id_Cliente"];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
                return p;
            }
        }

        public override void Save(Pedido entity)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(StringConnection))
            {
                string sql = "INSERT INTO Pedido (Id_Cliente, Num_Pedido, Dt_Entrega, Valor_Total) VALUES (@Cliente, @NumPedido, @DtEntrega, @Valor)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cliente", entity.IdCliente);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumPedido", entity.Numero);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtEntrega", entity.DtEntrega);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor", entity.ValorTotal);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

        public override void Update(Pedido entity)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(StringConnection))
            {
                string sql = "UPDATE Pedido SET Id_Cliente=@Cliente, Num_Pedido=@Numero, Dt_Entrega=@DtEntrega, Valor_Total=@Valor Where Id_Pedido=@Id";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", entity.Id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cliente", entity.IdCliente);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Numero", entity.Numero);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtEntrega", entity.DtEntrega);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor", entity.ValorTotal);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
public class PedidoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Pedido
        private GetPedidos respository = new GetPedidos();
        // GET: Pessoa
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(respository.GetAll());
        }

        // GET: Pessoa/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Pessoa/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Pedido pedido)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                respository.Save(pedido);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(pedido);
            }
        }

        // GET: Pessoa/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var pedido = respository.GetById(id);

            if (pedido == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(pedido);
        }

        // POST: Pessoa/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Pedido pedido)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                respository.Update(pedido);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(pedido);
            }
        }

        // POST: Pessoa/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            respository.DeleteById(id);
            return Json(respository.GetAll());
        }
    }
```

Repositório

```
public abstract class RepositoryData<TEntity, TKey>
                where TEntity : class
    {
        protected string StringConnection { get; } = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnTsL"].ConnectionString;

        public abstract List<TEntity> GetAll();
        public abstract TEntity GetById(TKey id);
        public abstract void Save(TEntity entity);
        public abstract void Update(TEntity entity);
        public abstract void Delete(TEntity entity);
        public abstract void DeleteById(TKey id);
    }
```

A View

```
@model IEnumerable<TSL.Models.GetPedidos>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**EDIT1**

O Erro

> O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do
>   tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TSL.Domain.Entities.Pedido]',
>   mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TSL.Models.GetPedidos]'.

A view está assim

```
@model List<TSL.Models.GetPedidos>
```

Comment: Poste o código da view onde você "define o tipo" dela. E o código do controller que manda os dados pra esta view.

Comment: Verdade, esqueci de postar o óbvio, o principal. Foi mal. Já vai

Comment: E a view, jovem?

Comment: A view espera uma lista do tipo **`GetPedidos`** se está sendo passado uma lista de **`Pedidos`**

Comment: Sugiro dar uma pesquisada no site, porque está cometendo erros que está cheio de informação mostrando que não pode fazer o que está fazendo. Por não aprender fazer o certo vai entrando em uma situação que seus códigos sempre estarão errados, até quando funcionam.

Answer (score 1):

O erro descreve o problema por si só.

Você pode simplesmente mudar a primeira linha da view para

```
@model List<TSL.Models.GetPedidos>
```

Fora isto, os tipos são incompatíveis. Leia o erro:

> O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do tipo **`List[TSL.Domain.Entities.Pedido]`**, mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo
>     **`List[TSL.Models.GetPedidos]`**.

Decida, ou você quer uma lista de `Pedido` ou uma lista de `GetPedidos`.

Comment: Quando criei a view, a fiz como lista(List). O erro persiste, mesmo alterando de **IEnumerable** para **List**

Comment: @pnet O erro não tem como persistir. Se está estourando algum erro, é outro.

Comment: LINQ, eu cliquei em cima da Action e adicionar View. Adicionei, escolhi o tipo que é **List**, selecionei a Model que éGetPedidos e marquei layout e **OK**. Como eu decido pelo tipo?

Comment: @pnet Ora, você quer usar um tipo, não? Se quer usá-lo você sabe qual é.